# How does postgres decide what multi-column index to use?

Tags: postgresql

Given the following ddl

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    c1 INTERVAL  NOT NULL,
    c2 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    c3 VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2)
);

CREATE INDEX c2_c1_index ON test (c2, c1);
```

The following query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE c1 = '1 minute'::INTERVAL
  AND c2 > '2020-06-27 00:00:00.0'::TIMESTAMP AND c2 < '2022-06-27 00:00:00.0'
ORDER BY c2
LIMIT 10000
```

returns this query plan in PostgreSQL 13.3

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..1102.23 rows=10000 width=40) (actual time=2.127..15.670 rows=10000 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using c2_c1_index on test  (cost=0.43..110174.94 rows=999957 width=40) (actual time=2.126..14.715 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((c2 > '2020-06-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (c2 < '2022-06-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (c1 = '00:01:00'::interval))
Planning Time: 0.290 ms
Execution Time: 16.201 ms
```

Why does postgres chooses `(c2, c1)` index instead of `(c1, c2)` primary key index? Based on the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) and many other SO answers, columns that are used for equality constraints should be leading column in the index definition. So `(c1, c2)` seems like a perfect index for that query especially considering sorting.

Also I should note that c1 only has 8 possible values but based on other answers ([e.g.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/76339)) it shouldn't really matter in multicolumn index.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the physical ordering of rows in the table is closely aligned with the order of c2, in other words that pg_stats.correlation is close to 1.0 for c2.  So it thinks that by following the index leading with c2, it will get to read the needed portion of the table mostly in order, minimizing the the number of block reads (because each block will have many needed rows) and making the reads it does need to do be more sequential than random.  That is a pretty big benefit.  The downside is that you need to filter out the rows with the wrong c1, but if most rows have the correct c1 ('1 minute' is the dominant value), that is not much of a downside.  Also, this filtering mostly involves CPU usage, and you can expect to get a lot of CPU work done in the time needed to wait for a random disk read.

You could reason that if the table is well correlated on c2, then it probably continues to be well correlated on it even after conditioning on c1, so the other index should enjoy the same benefit.  But, the planner does not reason that far ahead, it only looks at the correlation of the first column of the index.

Comment: Thanks!`pg_stats.correlation` is `-0.92` for `c2` but I assume -1 has the same meaning here? Also '1 minute' is indeed the dominant value. I noticed that indeed if use another value for `c1` predicate, the planner choses `(c1, c2)` index as expected. But I still cannot quite understand your reasoning in the second sentence. It's weird that postgres decides what index to use only by leading column.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's preferring that for reasons of cardinality. You hinted at this:

> Also I should note that c1 only has 8 possible values but based on other answers (e.g.) it shouldn't really matter in multicolumn index.

Postgres tracks the number of distinct values in each column, as well as how often the most frequent values occur.

Example of column statistics from [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/planner-stats-details.html):

> ```
> SELECT null_frac, n_distinct, most_common_vals, most_common_freqs > FROM pg_stats 
> WHERE tablename='tenk1' AND attname='stringu1';
>
> null_frac         | 0
> n_distinct        | 672
> most_common_vals  | {FDAAAA,NHAAAA,ATAAAA,BGAAAA,EBAAAA,MOAAAA,NDAAAA,OWAAAA,BHAAAA,BJAAAA}
> most_common_freqs | {0.00333333,0.00333333,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.003,0.00266667,0.00266667}
> ```

That means that if '1 minute' is one of the most common values in the c1 column, the planner would know approximately how many rows would be selected from just the `c1 = '1 minute'` part of the query. If that number is high, then it would be preferable to do an index scan on another index first, even if it's a range query. (Assuming the range query is selective enough, which it can estimate through a histogram. See the link above for how that works.)

An easy way to check this theory would be to re-create your table, with a different value for c1 in each row. Does it still prefer c2_c1_index?

Comment: By why would postgres planner assume that another index is better? And why it estimates indexes only by leading columns? As far as I understand if it uses `(c1, c2)` it will need to jump to `c1 = '1 minute'` portion of the index then to `c2=2020-06-27` and then just read everything until it reaches `c2='2022-06-27`. Isn't it supposed to be the fastest way? Regarding your last sentence - I noticed that if I replace `c1 = '1 minute'` with another value that is not dominated e.g. `c1 = '2 days'` it indeed uses `(c1,c2)` index

Comment: That's a really good point - I'm not sure why it couldn't do that. The above is just speculation - I'm not that familiar with postgres internals.